# Installing package in TeX Live with kpathsea

Tags: linux, unix

I use to put packages in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/` and to run `texhash` after.

Now, with `kparthsea`, it seems not working.

Where do I need to put my packages in order to TeX Live "sees" them or is there a *new* way to install packages?

```
# texhash
texhash: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
texhash: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
texhash: Done.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you issuing the `texhash` command with superuser privileges?

Comment: What kind of system is this? I don't quite recognize those paths. Did you run `texhash` as root?

Comment: According to your `texhash` output, the 'local' tree is `/usr/local/share/texmf` but you've put items in the non-hashed `/usr/share/texmf`: I'd try the one that is actually hashed, in the first instance.

Comment: I'm using debian sid. I've launched `texhash` as root (#). If I put my package in `/usr/local/texmf` and launched `texhash`, the package is not recognize.

Comment: As Joseph Wright said it should be `/usr/local/share/texmf`, your path is missing the `share` component.

Comment: Typo error, sorry. I did put my package in `/usr/local/share/texmf/` and it is not reconize after texhash

Comment: Have you tried installing the packages via `tlmgr` instead?

Comment: I didn't try tlmgr (maybe it's working) because of the workaround below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I specified directly a path :

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/package.el")
(require 'package)
```